# Hibernate - save large files

Tags: mysql, hibernate, large-files

I need to save large files (up to 5Mb) to DB (MySql) via Hibernate.

Changing max_allowed_packet param looks not good idea for me.

Is there a way or hibernate technics to do this? For example automatic breaking data into small portions and insert them one-by-one in 1 transaction.
I believe this should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is limited at server-side you can't modifiy this on client side, thus you need to increase `max_allowed_packet` to at least 5MB.
The maximum is 1GB [according to them manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html). So 5MB shouldn't be too large.